# How does all of the superfluid empty from the beaker?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

From what I understand, a **superfluid** is comprised of its normal fluid component and superfluid component (Landau's two fluid model). This normal fluid component has **viscosity**. What I don't understand, is how a beaker filled with $^{4}$He under the **critical temperature** will completely siphon itself out. Surely, only the superfluid component can do this, as the normal fluid component has viscosity? But according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollin_film , and many other sources, this is not the case. In the picture below, this superfluid seemingly "empties" itself. My reasoning suggests that only the superfluid component should empty itself.

[image]

Comment: "From what I understand, a superfluid is comprised of its normal fluid component and superfluid component." link please? from the wiki article on superfluidity , there are no  two components. "Superfluidity is the characteristic property of a fluid with zero viscosity" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluidity#Superfluidity_of_liquid_helium

Comment: That is a fundamental idea that Lev Landau proposed to explain discrepancies in experiments when measuring viscosity. If you search it up I believe you'll find a vast amount of resources on it. See here for example : http://cameronscott.co.uk/ . Just search it up on google :) Essentially the superfluid isn't entirely superfluid due to excitations from the ground state (it can only be so at T=0).

Comment: But for all practical purposes, any measurable volume is almost entirely superfluid, so the more energetic particles just get dragged along, so to speak.

Comment: And, please, both OP and @annav   "is comprised of" is not English.   Either "is composed of" or  "comprises" .

Comment: Haha, sure. But your comment is definitely not true. For all practical purposes a superfluid is not entirely superfluid - this entirely depends on how low the temperature is.

Comment: Helium 4 does consist of a normal and a superfluid component. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4#:~:text=Below%20the%20lambda%20line%20the%20liquid%20can%20be%20described%20by%20the%20so%2Dcalled%20two%2Dfluid%20model.%20It%20behaves%20as%20if%20it%20consists%20of%20two%20components%3A%20a%20normal%20component%2C%20which%20behaves%20like%20a%20normal%20fluid%2C%20and%20a%20superfluid%20component%20with%20zero%20viscosity%20and%20zero%20entropy.